# Prove that f is one-to-one on D

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, maximum-principle

Let $f$ be an analytic function on a disc $D$ whose center is the point $z_0$.

 Assume that $|f'(z)-f'(z_0 )|<|f'(z_0)| $ on D. 

Prove that $f$ is one-to-one on D.

Comment: To get a positive response on this site, you should try to indicate what you have tried. Also you shouldn't phrase your questions as a command "Prove ... ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square each side of the inequality to get
$$|f'(z)|^2 + |f'(z_0)|^2 -2\operatorname{Re}(f'(z)\overline{f'(z_0)})<|f'(z_0)|^2.$$
This implies that $\operatorname{Re}(f'(z)\overline{f'(z_0)})>0$ for all $z \in D$.
Now, if $z,w \in D$ and $z \neq w$, then
$$\operatorname{Re}\frac{\overline{f'(z_0)}(f(w)-f(z))}{w-z} = \int_{0}^1\operatorname{Re}\left(\overline{f'(z_0)}(f'(z+(w-z)t)\right) dt$$
which is easily seen to be strictly positive since $\operatorname{Re}(f'(\zeta)\overline{f'(z_0)})>0$ for all $\zeta \in D$. Thus $f(z)\neq f(w)$.

Comment: How can I get the inequality?

Comment: @volkov : Notice that if $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, then $|a-b|^2=(a-b)\overline{(a-b)}=(a-b)(\overline{a}-\overline{b}) = a\overline{a} + b\overline{b}-(a\overline{b}+\overline{a}b)$, which is equal to $|a|^2+|b|^2-(a\overline{b}+\overline{a\overline{b}})$ and use the fact that $\alpha+\overline{\alpha}=2\operatorname{Re}(\alpha)$.